# Ejabberd - Route message to users in offline_message_hook

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-hooks

I want to build a customer support chat app. There are `users` and an `admin`. Below admin there are `multiple sub-admins`. Initially the chat is initiated with admin only, but if the admin is offline I need to route the message to sub-admins.

`offline_message_hook` hook serves the purpose. I'll check if the `To` is admin, then I need to route the `Packet` to one of the sub-admins. How do I route/send the packet to other user within `offline_message_hook`. In short how do I change the `To` from the packet so that the packet is re-directed to the new sub-admin?

Here is what I've tried:-

```
offline_message_hook({_Action, #message{from = Peer, to = To} = Pkt} = Acc) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("Inside offline", []),
    ejabberd_router:route(From, To, Packet),
    ok.
```

I'm using `ejabberd 17.04.105`.

**Update**

After following `user2610053`'s advice, I did this:-

```
-spec offline_message_hook({any(), message()}) -> {any(), message()}.
offline_message_hook({_Action, Msg} = Acc) ->
    ejabberd_router:route(xmpp:set_to(Msg, 'praful@localhost')),
    {routed, Msg}.
```

Following is the error:-

```
15:13:12.291 [error] failed to route packet:
#message{id = <<"purple187f6502">>,type = chat,lang = <<"en">>,
         from = {jid,<<"praful2">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"Prafuls-MacBook-Pro">>,
                     <<"praful2">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"Prafuls-MacBook-Pro">>},
         to = praful@localhost,subject = [],
         body = [#text{lang = <<>>,data = <<"co=umon">>}],
         thread = undefined,
         sub_els = [{xmlel,<<"active">>,
                           [{<<"xmlns">>,
                             <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates">>}],
                           []}],
         meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}}}
Reason = {error,{{badrecord,jid},[{ejabberd_router,do_route,1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_router.erl"},{line,343}]},{ejabberd_router,route,1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_router.erl"},{line,87}]},{mod_sunshine,offline_message_hook,1,[{file,"src/mod_sunshine.erl"},{line,24}]},{ejabberd_hooks,safe_apply,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,380}]},{ejabberd_hooks,run_fold1,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,364}]},{ejabberd_sm,route,1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_sm.erl"},{line,138}]},{ejabberd_local,route,1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_local.erl"},{line,116}]},{ejabberd_router,do_route,1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_router.erl"},{line,348}]}]}}
```

The user `praful@localhost` exist. Please advice what exactly is wrong?

**Update2 - `UserReceivePacket Hook**

In `user_receive_packet` packet hook, upon using the same function `ejabberd_router:route(xmpp:set_to(Packet, jid:decode("praful@localhost"))),`  it throws an error saying :-

```
Hook user_receive_packet crashed when running mod_sunshine:user_receive_packet/1:
** Reason = {error,function_clause,[{jid,decode,[{file,"src/jid.erl"},{line,132}],["praful@localhost"]},{mod_sunshine,user_receive_packet,[{file,"src/mod_sunshine.erl"},{line,29}],1},{ejabberd_hooks,safe_apply,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,380}],4},{ejabberd_hooks,run_fold1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,364}],4},{ejabberd_c2s,process_info,[{file,"src/ejabberd_c2s.erl"},{line,231}],2},{ejabberd_hooks,safe_apply,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,380}],4},{ejabberd_hooks,run_fold1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,364}],4},{xmpp_stream_in,handle_info,[{file,"src/xmpp_stream_in.erl"},{line,373}],2}]}
```

So, I read about `function_clause`, but couldnt understand the same. What exactly is wrong over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking about [xmpp:set_to/2](https://github.com/processone/xmpp/blob/master/doc/API.md#set_to2). Here is an example:

```
offline_message_hook({_Action, Msg} = Acc) ->
  SubAdmins = get_sub_admins(Msg#message.to),
  lists:foreach(
    fun(Admin) ->
      ejabberd_router:route(xmpp:set_to(Msg, Admin))
    end, Admins),
  {routed, Msg}.
```

Comment: I followed your approach and did exactly the same, but I'm getting an error saying `failed to route packet`. Kindly see the updated question and provide your valuable advice.

Comment: In `to` field there should be record `#jid{}` and you're putting an atom there. Please read for details: https://github.com/processone/xmpp/blob/master/doc/API.md#jid

Comment: Used `jid:decode` and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hey, I'm receiving another error `function_clause` while routing the message in a similar way. Can you please have a look at the updated question. Thanks :)

Comment: You should use `binary()` type as input for `jid:decode/1`, not a `string()`.

Comment: Wow. Thanks.  :)

Comment: Can you also provide your valuable advice to this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543033/ejabberd-create-a-custom-stanza-get-set-subtags It will be very helpful!!! Thanks